# Yii Flash messages not displaying after install on production

Tags: flash, yii, message

Flash messages are perfectly working, when tested on my local environment. After I installed website on production, messages stopped working and do not appear anymore. I can not see any errors or warnings in app log. Does anyone know, what could be a problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well I found out by myself. I did not set session component in config file, which caused this problem. savePath has to be set, otherwise you might have this or similar issues.

```
'session' => array(
        'savePath' => dirname(__FILE__).'/../../sessions/'),
```